# Why does the NRSV-CE omit mentioning prayer and fasting in Matthew 17?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-matthew, textual-criticism

The NRSV-CE omits mentioning prayer and fasting, explaining in [footnote (g)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2017&version=NRSVCE#fen-NRSVCE-27993g):

> Matthew 17:20 Other ancient authorities add verse 21, *But this kind does not come out except by prayer and fasting*

[Rheims translation of Mt. 17:20](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=17&l=20-#x), based on Jerome's Latin *Vulgate*, says:

> But this kind is not cast out but by prayer and fasting.
> <sub>Hoc autem genus non ejicitur nisi per orationem et jejunium.</sub>

Why does the NRSV-CE omit mentioning prayer and fasting in Matthew 17?

Comment: Please be more careful of your use of tags! Here another one: [Why did Jesus keep himself and the disciples hungry and thirsty on some occasions?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72343/why-did-jesus-keep-himself-and-the-disciples-hungry-and-thirsty-on-some-occasion)

Comment: The tag should be gospel-of-matthew.

Comment: I have corrected. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, it wasn't the Catholic church that "removed" the verse. Plenty of other translations omit it too.

Answer (score 2):

By `"Other ancient authorities add verse 21, But this kind does not come out except by prayer and fasting"` they mean that not all sources contain verse 21, and they come to the conclusion that it is a later addition and not originally there. So the translators omit the verse to be closer to the original text (which is unknown). It reflects a decision what sources the translators deemed more authoritative than others. Maybe because they are older, or there are more sources which confirm this reading.

I can't say anything about how justified this is in this particular case, but this is what should be understood from the footnote.

Answer (score 1):

The NRSV-CE (1989) comes from the RSV-CE (1966), which is a 1946 Protestant translation with all [canonical books](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/55496/1787) included (pp. xviii & 9 of [*Which Bible Should You Read?*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4520)).

The [NRSV-CE omits "fasting" in its translation of Mk. 9:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%209:29&version=NRSVCE) ([so does the NABRE](http://www.usccb.org/bible/mk/9:29#49009029)):

> He said to them, “This kind can only come out through prayer.”

cf. [Rheims's Mk. 9:28](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=17&l=20-#x):

> And he said to them: This kind can go out by nothing, but by prayer and fasting.

Fasting scandalizes "modern man," so it's left out.

[*Which Bible Should You Read?*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7459) pp. 28-30 gives another example of a glaring omission of verses in nominally Catholic bibles: [Ecclesiasticus (Sirach) 24:24](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-#x)-31. The Douay version reads:

> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-24#x) [[24]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-#x) **I am the mother of fair love, and of fear, and of knowledge, and of holy hope.**
> *Ego mater pulchrae dilectionis, et timoris, et agnitionis, et sanctae spei.*
>
> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-25#x) [[25]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=25-#x) **In me is all grace of the way and of the truth, in me is all hope of life and of virtue.**
>   *In me gratia omnis viae et veritatis : in me omnis spes vitae et virtutis.*
>
> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-26#x) [[26]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=26-#x) Come over to me, all ye that desire me, and be filled with my fruits.
>   *Transite ad me, omnes qui concupiscitis me, et a generationibus meis implemini :*
>
> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-27#x) [[27]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=27-#x) For my spirit is sweet above honey, and my inheritance above honey and the honeycomb.
>   *spiritus enim meus super mel dulcis, et haereditas mea super mel et favum.*
>
> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-28#x) [[28]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=28-#x) My memory is unto everlasting generations.
>   *Memoria mea in generatione saeculorum.*
>
> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-29#x) [[29]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=29-#x) They that eat me, shall yet hunger: and they that drink me, shall yet thirst.
>   *Qui edunt me, adhuc esurient, et qui bibunt me, adhuc sitient.*
>
> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-30#x) [[30]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=30-#x) He that hearkeneth to me, shall not be confounded: and they that work by me, shall not sin.
>   *Qui audit me non confundetur, et qui operantur in me non peccabunt :*
>
> [**...**](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=24-31#x) [[31]](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=24&l=31-#x) **They that explain me shall have life everlasting.**
>   *qui elucidant me, vitam aeternam habebunt.*

But the [NRSV-CE of Sirach 24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Sirach%2024&version=NRSVCE) omits the bold verses above, and NRSV-CE v. 19 corresponds to Douay v. 26! Douay vv. 24-25's [omission is explained in a footnote of the NSRV-CE](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Sirach%2024&version=NRSVCE#fen-NRSVCE-20787e), but the NRSV-CE doesn't explain its omission of Douay v. 31 in a footnote!

These verses were probably omitted because the Catholic Church uses them in the liturgy for various feasts of the Blessed Virgin Mother, and mention of her is a scandal to Protestants.

According to [*Which Bible Should You Read?*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7459) p. 29,

> All together, Chapter 24 of Ecclesiasticus (Sirach) has some […] 13 fewer verses in the CRSV [Catholic Revised Standard Version] than the Vulgate and DRB [Douay-Rheims Bible]!

Indeed, the Douay version has 47 verses, and the NRSV-CE has only 34.

The "old Latin vulgate" is the only official edition of Holy Scriptures for the universal Church, [as defined in the Council of Trent](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/55496/1787).

Comment: Geremia, to me there was an apparent clash between V.20 and V.21 with the former saying:   He said to them, “Because of your little faith. For truly I tell you, if you have faith the size of a  mustard seed, you will say to this mountain, ‘Move from here to there,’ and it will move; and nothing will be impossible for you.”. If Jesus meant that one needs to have faith, fasting and prayer - all at the same time, it would, at least for some, invalidate the theory of `faith alone saves '. I think that your remark   ``Fasting scandalizes "modern man," so it's left out.'" has a personal touch .

Comment: Regarding fasting scandalizing "modern man": That reason is frequently given by [Modernists](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72030/1787) (such as those of [Concilium, who created the _Novus Ordo_ Mass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6kE1EAF4QE&list=PLDA085477E90AC096&index=11)) to justify stripping anything with "negative theology" such as:

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan "• Divine wrath
• Punishment in this life for sin
• Condemnations of impurity
• The "narrow gate" to salvation
• Hell
• The evils of the world
• Dangers from heretics, pagans and Jews
• The "outmoded" New Testament teaching on the role of women.
• Punishment for receiving the Eucharist unworthily." and anything un-ecumenical such as emphasis on Mary.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have your opinion on the other view-point relating to `clash of concepts' as referred to in my comment that is Verse 20 Vs Verse 21.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Perhaps you can open another question about that specifically.